# Migrations failed: When trying to install apt and pypi packages (both) in airflow

Tags: docker, kubernetes, airflow, airflow-scheduler, airflow-2.x

**My dockerfile -**

```
FROM apache/airflow:2.2.3

COPY /airflow/requirements.txt /requirements.txt

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r /requirements.txt

USER root

# Update aptitude with new repo
RUN apt-get update

# Install software 
RUN apt-get install -y git

USER airflow
```

reference for this dockerfile - https://airflow.apache.org/docs/docker-stack/build.html#a-pypi-package-example

While I install my helm chart for airflow, it fails at migration for webserver, worker, scheduler and sometimes triggerer as well. All fails with init migrations container.

Error in migrations file -

```
File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/alembic/script/base.py", line 259, in _catch_revision_errors
raise util.CommandError(resolution) from re
alembic.util.exc.CommandError: Can't locate revision identified by '587bdf053233'
```

My question is -
Is my dockerfile right?
What are the basic steps to debug this error? (k8s, openshift, docker, airflow)

Comment: https://github.com/apache/airflow/discussions/22977

Comment: This might be helpful for some